# Drupal site not behaving - process of elimination

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I have two versions of a Drupal site running on my local dev environment. Site X boots perfectly; site Y doesn't - rather than running index.php, install.php is called.

So far, I've:

- Stepped through site Y with a PHP debugger; index.php does not seem to be called at all.
- Pointed site Y at the database for site X to see whether there were database corruption issues; seemingly, there weren't.
- Swapped out the .htaccess file in site Y for the .htaccess file in site X. No joy.

What should I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the above provides a walkthrough, so question answered.

Answer (score 1):

Does settings.php exist in site Y and does it have the correct database information?

Also, are these two seperate drupal installs, or one drupal install setup multisite?

Comment: Thanks.

settings.php does exist in site Y, and it seems to have the correct database information. When I point site X at the database for site Y, site X boots.

These are two separate, single-site Drupal installs.

Comment: What if you try backing up that database, and dropping in a blank settings.php (copied from default.settings.php) and run the install process, does it connect to the right database then?

Comment: Thanks! This didn't quite work but I've now got site Y booting. I'm getting Access Denied messages, though, and the theme isn't loading - I think this might be something to do with site Y being built in a Wintel environment; I use OSX. I'll keep plugging away, but would appreciate any inspired insights :)

Comment: ok, turns out it was a pretty standard D6 perms issue - set the perms on each folder in sites/ for site Y to the same as the perms for site X, et voila. tks for your help, Kevin :)